# Writing C# SDKs with dynamic responses and casting to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, sdk, json.net

For example;

I have a class called "User";

```
public class User 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

Awesome! Now, lets make a request to our REST API;

```
GET: api.com/users/123
RESPONSE: 
{ 
    name : "Erik", 
    jobs : [ { id : 1 }, { id: 2 } ] 
}
```

Great! Now, lets do something fun with query strings and expand the jobs list.

```
GET: api.com/users/123?$expand=Jobs
RESPONSE: 
{ 
    name : "Erik", 
    jobs : [ 
        { 
            id : 1,
            name : "My Job",
            address : "1515 My Street Rd. 20144, VA"
        }, 
        { 
            id : 2,
            name : "My Job 2",
            address : "9595 My Street Rd. 20144, VA"
        }
    ] 
}
```

But uh oh... We can't use the original User class. This is because the Job model looks like this;

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So naturally, the JSON serializer doesn't know how to cast it's "expanded" response.

What are my options?

Can I override the Jobs property in the User class? Like;

```
public class UserWithExpandingJobs : User
{
    public List<JobExpanded> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

So that it is hides the initial inherited value and replaces it with a new Job model like this;

```
public class JobExpanded : Job
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

All this expanding is making my head hurt! It seems SO verbose.

Can anyone coach me through what I should be thinking or trying to do to minimize the SDK footprint.

Oh, btw... It's not letting me override Jobs because it is a different type. Thoughts?

Comment: You can use `new` to introduce a new member with the same name - but it won't (and *shouldn't*) override the existing member. It's not at all clear how you'd expect any of this code to be *used* though. If you really feel the extra 10 lines of code is too verbose, why not just use `dynamic` for everything? Don't bother declaring types at all...

Comment: So your API is returning the strongly typed .NET objects to be serialized in the response?  Returning the generic Object will allow the serializer to handle different object structures at the same endpoint.

Comment: @JonSkeet - MY concern is that I've had to create two new objects. "UserWithExpandingJobs" and "JobExpanded". Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @Erik5388: Well you've got different data types in terms of how much information is present. You *could* just have the expanded type, and return a version without as much information present when you don't have the expanded view...